# Random number sequence generator in R with advanced criteria

Tags: r, random

I'm looking to generate a random number sequence with 14 numbers between 1 & 25 (inclusive). Which I can do in R using `> sample (1:25, 14)`. However, for some of the sequences I need certain numbers excluded (2,3,4,5,6,16,21,etc.). I also need to make sure certain numbers don't fall within the first 4 numbers of the sequences (i.e.1-6, 16, 21,etc.) I also need certain sequences where certain numbers appear twice between the 5th and 14th position.

Sorry if it's not clear, but I basically need a random number sequence generator in R which

- includes exclusion criteria
- specifies what position certain numbers appear in
- allows for certain number to appear twice in the sequence after a certain position.

If anyone knows of function that could do this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: You already have everything you need. Combine `c` and multiple calls to `sample` and you're all set. Any function that achieves your desired result will just be a combination of those two functions (and maybe `sort` and some indexing).

Answer (score 3):

This function does what you want:

```
specialSample <- function(yourSample, sampleTimes, exclusion, firstFour, appearTwice){
excludedSample <- yourSample[!yourSample%in%exclusion]
first <- sample(excludedSample,1,prob=excludedSample%in%firstFour)
firstposition <- sample(1:4,1)
second <- sample(excludedSample,1,prob=excludedSample%in%appearTwice)
twice <- c(second,second)
sampler <- sample(excludedSample,sampleTimes-length(exclude),replace=TRUE)
positions <- sample(5:14,2)
result <- sampler
result[firstposition] <- first
result[positions] <- twice
return(result)
}
```

The arguments are

`yourSample` is the sequence you are sampling form

`sampleTimes` is how many values you want in your sample (I have specified `replace=TRUE` if you want `replace=FALSE` then `length(sampleTimes)` must be < `length(yourSample)`

`exclusion` is the numbers you want excluded

`firstFour` numbers that you want one of to be in the first four

`appearTwice` numbers you want to appear twice in certain random positions

```
 > numbers <- 1:25
 > exclude <- c(2,4,8)
 > firstFour <- 1:4
 > appearTwice <- c(11,12)

 > test <- specialSample(numbers,25,exclude,firstFour,appearTwice)
!> test
  [1] 12 23  3  9 10 10 21 12  7 17 24 15 22 12  3 14  9  9  1  6 19 15
```

The basic idea is to exploit indexing of vectors `vec[positionN]<-value` and probability of sampling to get the values you want in the places you want.